# Is it possible to programmatically Invert color of a view or layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm building an app which can show pdfs. I used [this](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) library to load and show pdfs. I want to add a night mode option to my pdfs where black is rendered as white, white as black and so on.

My question is, is it possible to invert all the colors of a view/layout without fiddling with native code?

For example [Moon Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flyersoft.moonreader) app has night mode option:

> **Night Mode off:**
>   [image: Night Mode off]
>
> **Night Mode Enabled:**
>   [image: Night Mode Enabled]

Comment: this is an interesting question, only way i know to do this is by entirely changing the theme or style

Comment: @a_local_nobody as far as i know, updating theme will change some fixed set of values to other values, but can not change a set of color to another color, defined by some logic

Comment: in a style, if you have textColor as white, and then in another styles file change textColor to black, would that not achieve what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not a proper solution to the question, but as a matter of fact, the library used [AndroidPdfViewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) in the question, has added support for Night Mode on `3.1.0-beta.1` version.

All you have to do is, call nightMode function with boolean true variable.

```
pdfView.fromAsset(String)
    .nightMode(true) // toggle night mode
    .load();
```

and Add this line to `proguard.pro`

```
-keep class com.shockwave.**
```